# How to use regex to replace a sentence that has a question mark

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write some code to translate Shakespearean English to Modern English but I'm having a problem using re.sub to replace sentences that end with a question mark. When I replace the sentence, I get 2 question marks at the end.

I've tried adding "\?" and "\?" to the substitute string but that does not work.

```
p = 'Mine eye hath played the painter and hath stelled. Thy beauty form in table of my heart; My body is the frame wherein this held, and perspective it is the painters art. For through the painter must you see his skill, to find where your true image pictured lies; Which in my bosoms shop is hanging still, that hath his windows glazed with thine eyes. Now see what good turns eyes for eyes have done. Have mine eyes have drawn thy shape, and thine for me? Are windows to my breast, where-through the sun delights to peep, to gaze therein on thee; Yet eyes this cunning want to grace their art; They draw but what they see, know not the heart.'
s = 'Have mine eyes have drawn thy shape, and thine for me?'
s2 = re.sub(r'^(.*?(mine.*?){0})mine', r'\1my', s)
p = re.sub(s,s2,p)
print(p)
```

Below is the output, which as you will note has 2 question marks at the end of the sentence I replaced.

```
Mine eye hath played the painter and hath stelled. Thy beauty form in table of my heart; My body is the frame wherein this held, and perspective it is the painters art. For through the painter must you see his skill, to find where your true image pictured lies; Which in my bosoms shop is hanging still, that hath his windows glazed with thine eyes. Now see what good turns eyes for eyes have done. Have my eyes have drawn thy shape, and thine for me?? Are windows to my breast, where-through the sun delights to peep, to gaze therein on thee; Yet eyes this cunning want to grace their art; They draw but what they see, know not the heart.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `s` string is used as a *regular expression* in `re.sub(s,...)` so you have to *escape* special characters if not already done.

In that case, failing to do that tells regex module to search for 0 or 1 `e` character. The following `?` is not matched in the input string, which explains that you get the old `?` *and* the new `?`

Here I'd do:

```
p = re.sub(re.escape(s),s2,p)
```

(which is much more generic than: `p = re.sub(s.replace("?",r"\?"),s2,p)`)